# Flutter app hangs on white screen or shuts instantly during Xcode deploy

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I have had no issue using the iOS emulator with VSCode or Xcode. However for the last month I haven't been able to deploy to my phone. I've tried with various simple apps that run fine in emulators. Every time, the app installs on the phone ok but either opens and hangs on a white screen or closes instantly when opened.

In Xcode, the problem is always Thread 1:

```
    dyld`__abort_with_payload:
    0x100b6f5dc <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
    0x100b6f5e0 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x100b6f5e4 <+8>:  b.lo   0x100b6f600               ; <+36> (Thread 1: signal SIGABRT)
    0x100b6f5e8 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x100b6f5ec <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x100b6f5f0 <+20>: bl     0x100b6dbe8               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x100b6f5f4 <+24>: mov    sp, x29
    0x100b6f5f8 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x100b6f5fc <+32>: ret    
    0x100b6f600 <+36>: ret    


Here is another printout from the output section:

    dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Flutter.framework/Flutter
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F63D0E77-7683-4017-A7E5-CF9E224345E1/Runner.app/Runner
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F63D0E77-7683-4017-A7E5-CF9E224345E1/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F63D0E77-7683-4017-A7E5-CF9E224345E1/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F63D0E77-7683-4017-A7E5-CF9E224345E1/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: stat() failed with errno=25
(lldb)
```

Does this make sense to anyone? It's happening with every app so either I'm doing something wrong for all of them or I've got an issue with my setup.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49504#issuecomment-592767041

Comment: Installing the new beta iOS solved it thanks